Export large dataframe to json file without storing the whole string in memory
I have a very large dataframe when exported to json is about 3.5GB. I noticed that while exporting it to json, it is consuming extra 7GB memory. Looks like panda's dataframe is holding the whole json string (3.5GB) in memory first and then only writing to file instead of directly streaming the generated string/bytes into file. On top on that, extra 3.5GB is also being consumed while writing the json string to file, i think, to encode string to bytes. Why is it not encoding in chunks?
Is there a way to export json directly into file without storing whole json in memory first, i.e. only storing some buffer (about 10-50mb) in memory.
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

large_df: pd.DataFrame
sleep(5)

with open("exported.json", "w") as f:
    large_df.to_json(f, orient="records", date_format="iso")

sleep(5)


Memory profile is generated using memory-profiler.

You can do something like this:
def slice_df(df, chunk_size=1000):
    if chunk_size < 1:
        raise ValueError("Invalid value: chunk_size should be > 0")
    i = 0
    is_last = False
    while i < len(df):
        if i + chunk_size >= len(df):
            is_last = True
        yield is_last, df[i:i+chunk_size]
        i = i + chunk_size

large_df_chunks = slice_df(large_df)

with open("exported.json", "w") as f:
    f.write('[')
    for is_last, df_chunk in large_df_chunks:
        f.write(df_chunk.to_json(orient="records", date_format="iso")[1:-1])
        if not is_last:
            f.write(',')
    f.write(']')


There is already some default value for buffering so that parameter is not a problem. The problem is the logic of in pandas dataframe.json function. It generates the string first and then writes to file: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0962dcc76a602bfe6623a0250f0ce50cbb912fd7/pandas/io/json/_json.py#L191-L211

Got it, I've modified my answer based on your comment, thanks, I hope it will help you now.
